# flux constants - multiple files or single file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

Should i have one constants file for the whole app or split it one for each coresponding store , action ?

My thought's are one for the whole app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of preference.

If you have a couple dozen constants, I don't see a downside to keeping them in one file. If you have, say, hundreds of constants it may make sense to split them up—not for any technical reason, but just to make it easier for you and your teammates to find the ones you're looking for without digging through many pages of the same file.

Either way you should do your best to group them logically—and even in a file as simple as a list of constants, generous whitespace and comments will make everyone's lives easier.